# Can "Technology always develops from the primitive via the complicated to the simple" be attributed to de Saint-Exupéry?

Tags: citations

The quote

> Technology always develops from the primitive via the complicated to the simple

is commonly attributed to Antoine de Saint-Exupéry. There is also a very similar quotation, attributed to Kurt Biedenkopf:

> Progress is the way from the primitive via the complicated to the simple solution

I've tried looking for this quote, but could not find anything apart from third-party references to the quote. Has de Saint-Exupéry written that quote and if so, in which original text could it be found?

Comment: I have found [a company website](https://unibon.cz/fr/qui-sommes-nous/) which cites him as “_le progrès technique mène toujours du primitif au simple en passant par le compliqué_” but I cannot find any other source for it. [This article](http://lilienthal-museum.de/olma/f_soest.htm) also seems to refer to something similar without source…

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find any evidence Saint-Exupéry actually wrote it that way. It is possible the saying was built from this paragraph:

> *Il semble que tout l'effort industriel de l'homme, tous ses calculs, toutes ses nuits de veille sur les épures, n'aboutissent, comme signes visibles, qu'à la seule simplicité, comme s'il fallait l'expérience de plusieurs générations pour dégager peu à peu la courbe d'une colonne, d'une carène, ou d'un fuselage d'avion, jusqu'à leur rendre la pureté élémentaire de la courbe d'un sein ou d'une épaule. Il semble que le travail des ingénieurs, des dessinateurs, des calculateurs du bureau d'études ne soit ainsi, en apparence, que de polir et d'effacer, d'alléger ce raccord, d'équilibrer cette aile, jusqu'à ce qu'on ne la remarque plus, jusqu'à ce qu'il n'y ait plus une aile accrochée à un fuselage, mais une forme parfaitement épanouie, enfin dégagée de sa gangue, une sorte d'ensemble spontané, mystérieusement lié, et de la même qualité que celle du poème. **Il semble que la perfection soit atteinte non quand il n'y a plus rien à ajouter, mais quand il n'y a plus rien à retrancher.** Au terme de son évolution, la machine se dissimule.*
>
> *Terre des hommes*, 1939

The sentence I bolded is very famous in France.

Comment: Indeed, it's famous in English too (although variously translated).